# Two Apple ids and just want one

Tags: email, apple-id, accounts, iphone

I changed my e-mail from hotmail to gmail during 2013.

I want my Apple id to follow that.

The old email account is still there when I configured my iPhone 5s and tryied to install my icloud and phone settings.

The new phone wants both apple ids. Why?

---

**Question :** How do I remove my old Apple-id from my phone?

Comment: Also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124347/new-iphone-asks-for-an-apple-id-login-that-is-not-mine

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming when you say "both Apple IDs", that you mean an Apple ID using your Gmail account, and an Apple ID using your Hotmail account.

It asked you for passwords to both of those Apple IDs because you have purchases or free items licensed under both IDs.